# SQL Server DBCC CHECKDB Being Run On Bootup

Tags: sql-server-2008, dbcc

We've noticed that on bootup, there are CHECKDBs being run against all databases on the instance being restarted. At first I assumed it was standard procedure and did some research. I found a couple of posts stating that this happenswhen the server goes down without allowing the dabases to properly close.

Although that makes good sense, why are these CHECKDBs only takeing a couple of minutes to spin through? Even PHYICALONLY should take an hour or more to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is not really running a CHECKDB at startup. Michael Campbell does a good job of explaining what you're seeing: [Why is SQL Server running DBCC CHECKDB against my databases at Server Startup?](http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/practical-sql-server-45/sql-server/why-is-sql-server-running-dbcc-checkdb-against-my-databases-at-server-startup-139458)

Comment: Thanks Joe! This explains a lot.